# How do I automatically send an email every time a person fills out a form in Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, field-update, send-email, cloudpagesurl

I have the following problem. I created a landing page using the standard Cloud Capture data extension because it was the only way to get the form to send data to the extension. But I needed an email to be sent to a commercial person every time someone filled out the form. This email must contain the data of the person who filled out the form.

I was wondering if you can do this and how. I already created the email template by placing the variables, I just need to have this email sent to a specific person every time a contact enters the data extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using SmartCapture in your Cloud Page and you have Journey Builder in your account, this is pretty easy, but it does take a few things set up correctly.

1. Ensure the "Commercial Person" is in your All Subscribers list with a non-personally identifiable SubscriberKey.
2. Make sure your Data Extension is Sendable, similar to this one:

[image]

3. When adding your SmartCapture Form, check the "Use in Journey Builder" checkbox and add the SubscriberKey field as a hidden field in your form. Its value should be that of your commercial person's SubscriberKey:

   [image]
4. Set up a new Journey, choosing "CloudPages" as your entry type and your SmartCapture form as the source.
5. On your Journey Settings, ensure you're using the email address from Contacts and not that of the Entry Source:

[image]

6. Add an email activity to your journey that will be used to send the details of the form post to the commercial person

Comment: Thank you so much!!! This tutorial helped me a lot! Now it's everything working :)